# How To Fetch Facebook Activity Feed of A Particular User

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Do any one know how to fetch activity feed of an user who is associated with an app id ?

I am able to fetch the list of users who are associated with an app id by using this code

```
<?php 
    require "facebook.php";
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => '',
        'secret' => '',
    )); 
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    if ($user) {
      try {
            $result = $facebook->api(array(
            "method"    => "fql.query",
            "query"     => "SELECT uid, name, pic_square, activities FROM user
            WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2 = me()) and  is_app_user"
        ));
    echo "<pre>"; 
    print_r($result);
?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 14529121124
            [name] => Saurabh
            [pic_square] => http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-ash4/187195_1452918224_6692287_q.jpg
            [activities] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 100000565666371
            [name] => Abhijeet
            [pic_square] => http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-prn1/157718_100000289210371_1409561577_q.jpg
            [activities] => 
        )

)
```

Now i just want to fetch activity feed of these 2 users **(User Id: 14529121124 ,  100000565666371)** individually who are associated with this **(54975723243503) app_id.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use graph API : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Search for "feed" in that page

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think the feed option will return all the feed of an user. Is there any way to filter the feed (I just want to fetch the feed or activity related to my app or website.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to query the FQL [stream](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream) table or the Graph API feed object:

Since you're working with FQL, I'll give an example using FQL. I did some quick testing, and the `stream` table doesn't allow you to use the `IN` keyword to select streams from multiple sources, so you'll need to make two separate calls, first to get the `user_id`s, second to get the stream.

Try this:

```
$queries = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($result as $item) {
   $queries['user_stream'.$i] =>
     "SELECT source_id, created_time, message, attachment FROM stream 
        WHERE source_id = " . $item['uid'];
   $i++;
}

$result2 = $facebook->api(array(
        "method"    => "fql.multiquery",
        "queries"     => json_encode($queries)
         ));
```